# mail header issue in sendmail in CentOs 6

Tags: email, header, sendmail

I have setup centOs 6 on rackspace server, and installed Apache PHP & other modules. 
I also installed sendmail to use mail() function from PHP, it working, but i am not able to set my own header in mail().

```
 $to = "myemail@gmail.com"; 
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";


 $from = " Team <my@odomain.com>"; 
 $headers  = "From: $from\r\n"; 
 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" ;
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";

 if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }
```

But i getting spam emails with header "Apache apache@server". Header is not setting.
I also tried "-f emailaddress", but not working.

What should i do? I had also try some sendmail configuration but still not solved.

Ritesh

Answer (score 0):

Replace `\r\n` with `\n` in the line `$headers = "From: $from\r\n";`